# Joomla 3.1 full article image to be "clickable" how can I add a link to the picture?

Tags: html, joomla, article, joomla3.1

I want to add link to the full article image, how to do this? I have to modify the article component?

I want to add to the component an option, Image link like this ...
[image]

It is possible ?

Or I have another Idea, It would be the best if the full article image shows floated near the article in a given size (example: 400px) and when the users click on the picture, the picture will show in the real size (example: 800px, or full screen) in a light box... it exists plugins for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy answer to this. You will need to create some overrides for the article/category/blog views components/com_content/views.. on the frontend. You will also need to modify the core files administrator/com_content/models... http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Your best option really is to put the image in your article using the editor and adding a link to it with the editor. You would be looking to do a very time intensive task. You can the assign a css class to the image and float or size it however you wanted.